# java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

In my ejb client code

```
package client;

import com.homeif.HelloWorldHome;
import com.remoteif.HelloWorld;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;
import java.awt.image.LookupOp;
import java.util.Properties;

public class HelloClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
            Object object = initialContext.lookup("HelloWorldBean");
            System.out.println("Object:-"+object);
            HelloWorldHome home =
                    (HelloWorldHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(object,
                            HelloWorldHome.class);

            HelloWorld myHelloWorld = home.create();

            String message = myHelloWorld.sayHello();
            System.out.println(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(" Error : " + e);
            System.exit(2);
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
 java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.remoting.Version.getDefaultVersion()
```

It is in the following line

```
    HelloWorldHome home =(HelloWorldHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(object,                           HelloWorldHome.class);
```

Why it is so? How can I solve this?

The jar I am using is jboss-remoting-1.4.1.final.jar. But the Version class in it doesn't contain the function getDefaultVersion. Can anyone please tell me the jar file for this?

Answer (score 0):

I added jboss-remoting-4.2.2.GA.jar. that solved the problem